# Application profiling / performance testing

Tags: android, react-native, flutter

(Note: I want to test it on android)

Hi,

I have an application in react native and a similar application made with flutter. I want to profile / test it and see cpu usage, check when they drop frames, etc.

I know that applications in debugmode are worse in performance. So I thought I have to test these two applications in release mode, because I dont know how much debugmode hold these applications back.
But from my understanding android profiling does not work in release mode (don't know about systrace, still have some problems with it).

So my question, how do I compare these 2 apps? Is there a way to do with release builds? Or should I test and compare it with a debug build?

[Edit]
I read that flutter has a profile build which builds closely to a release build, is running in debugmode and turning off dev mode in react-native about the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Profile mode is how you would test your Flutter app as if it is running in release.

- [flutter/Flutter's build modes: Profile](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes#profile)

It uses DevTools which can help debug the UI, memory, performance, logs, etc.

- [flutter/DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview)

And what you noted, *"builds closely to a release build"*, is mentioned at:

- [flutter/Flutter performance profiling: Run in profile mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance#run-in-profile-mode)

> Flutter’s profile mode compiles and launches your application almost
>   identically to release mode

The last two links provide a wealth of information on how to use each of their features.

You can even check out [flutter/Performance best practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices) to make sure you've got the best experience before you jump into testing.